# Retrieval of image from the URL in linked in

Tags: linkedin-api

How does linked in retrieves the image from the URL? Is there any tag for it?

As i tried to post the url link in the post window of linked in, it automatically displayed the image available in the particular URL, in what basis does the image is retreived. as there is any tags does linked in searches for it to display.

Please help me on the same

Comment: This should be asked on webmasters I think. Anyhow, look up "meta tags"

Answer (score 0):

It uses [opengraph](http://ogp.me/):

> sample open graph meta tags

(snippet from https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin)

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
  <meta property="og:title" content="My Shared Article Title" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Description of shared article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://example.com/my_article.html" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/foo.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
   …
</body>
</html>
```